# Unreal Engine 4: dynamic multicast delegate binding

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

at the moment i am playing around with unreal engine's HTTP module and wrote a class to query weather information from a web service.
First I created a general HTTP service class like this:

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Runtime/Online/HTTP/Public/Http.h"
#include "Json.h"
#include "HTTPService.generated.h"

DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam(FHTTPOnResponseRecievedDelegate, const FString&, HttpData);

UCLASS()
class THMVRAYPLUGIN_API UHTTPService : public UClass
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

private:
    FHttpModule * Http;
    FString AuthorizationHeader = "Authorization";
    void SetAuthorizationHash(FString Hash, TSharedRef<IHttpRequest>& Request);
    void SetRequestHeaders(TSharedRef<IHttpRequest>& Request);
    bool ResponseIsValid(FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful);
    virtual void OnResponseReceived(FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccesful);
    void Send(TSharedRef<IHttpRequest>& Request);

public:    
    UHTTPService();
    FHTTPOnResponseRecievedDelegate responseReceived;
    TSharedRef<IHttpRequest> GetRequest(FString request);
};
```

I declared a dynamic multicast delegate for the OnResponseReceived event.
This method broadcasts the received JSON string:

```
void UHTTPService::OnResponseReceived(FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccesful)
{
    if (ResponseIsValid(Response, bWasSuccesful)) {
        FString JSONString = Response->GetContentAsString();
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Http Response: %s"), *JSONString);
        responseReceived.Broadcast(JSONString);
    }

}
```

After that I created a subclass of the HTTPService class for a specific web API:

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "HTTPService.h"
#include "HTTPWeatherService.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class THMVRAYPLUGIN_API UHTTPWeatherService : public UHTTPService
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

private:
    FString APIBaseURL = "xxxx";
    FString APIKey = "xxxx";

public:    
    UHTTPWeatherService();
    void queryWeatherAPIForCoords(float lat, float lon);

};
```

Now I want to use this for a custom actor, which I wrote.
In the details panel customization I created a custom row to hold a button like this:

```
//....
        auto OnWeatherButtonClicked = [myActor]
        {
            float lat = myActor->latitude;
            float lon = myActor->longitude;
            UHTTPWeatherService * weatherService = NewObject<UHTTPWeatherService>();
            weatherService->queryWeatherAPIForCoords(lat, lon);
            return FReply::Handled();
        };

        experimentalGroup.AddWidgetRow()
            .ValueContent()
            [
                SNew(SButton)
                .Text(LOCTEXT("Current weather", "Get weather at current location"))
                .ToolTipText(LOCTEXT("Uses a web api to get information on the current weather at the current coords","Uses a web api to get information on the current weather at the current coords"))
                .OnClicked_Lambda(OnWeatherButtonClicked)
            ];
//...
```

When you click the button, it fires the function to query the web api.
What I want to do now is to bind a function to the dynamic multicast delegate.
I want to fire a method of my custom actor when the response was received.
How would you do that? What would be a good program structure?
Can anybody provide a piece of code as reference?

​​​​​​​Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Use `responseReceived.AddDynamic` to register your object to the delegate. However your service might be garbage collected, save a reference to it as a `UPROPERTY` in your class.

Comment: @Rotem I already tried it like this. I didn't get any compilation errors but the unreal engine crashed. Could you provide some referene code?

Comment: Reference implementation of multicast delegates is easily found online and in the engine source code itself. Where did the engine crash?

Comment: @Rotem the engine crashes right at startup. What I did is the following; 1) I added the UPROPERTY to hold the weather service class `UPROPERTY()
  class UHTTPWeatherService * weatherService = NewObject<UHTTPWeatherService>();` 2) I added a UFUNCTION which to call when a response was received `UFUNCTION()
  void logResponse(const FString& response)` 3) I called AddDynamic OnPostinitProperties `void ATHMForVRayActor::PostInitProperties()
{
 Super::PostInitProperties();
 weatherService->responseReceived.AddDynamic(this, &ATHMForVRayActor::logResponse); }`

Comment: Try not constructing your object in the field initializer, but only when needed. Remember there are CDOs in Unreal.

Comment: @Rotem Okay now it doesn't crash anymore but the method i want to bind was not executed. This is the method I call when the user clicks the custom button: `ATHMForVRayActor::bindToWeatherDelegate()
{
 if (weatherService == nullptr) {
  weatherService = NewObject<UHTTPWeatherService>();
  weatherService->responseReceived.AddDynamic(this, &ATHMForVRayActor::logResponse);
 }
}`

Comment: Is `logResponse` a `UFUNCTION` ?

Comment: @Rotem yes it is

Comment: Sorry, that's all I got at the moment. I assume that "Http Response: %s" *is* being printed, right?

Comment: @Rotem yes the OnResponseReceived method fires ;/

Comment: I'd be happy to take a look at the code if you want to upload it to a pastebin or something. Multicast delegates *do* generally work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to make it work with a `DECLARE_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam`instead of a `DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam`.